# React-Native Audio Waveform editor

Tags: reactjs, react-native, audio, waveform, react-native-sound

I am planning to build an audio editor app with react-native. The functionalities include having a textbox where user can provide the URL for any audio file. Once the file is loaded on the UI, it will be played with a Waveform UI. User can select the start and endpoints of the audio by moving the slider on the waveform and once it's fixed, the app will get the start-time and end-time of the selected waveform, which will be then sent to the backend to cut the audio(probably using FFmpeg library).
I need but can't seem to find any react-native library that allows the user to interact with the waveform.
The UI can be somewhat similar to:

[image]

Comment: try react-native-audiowaveform:
https://github.com/juananime/react-native-audiowaveform

Comment: @Oleg: Does this library allow a user to set start-time and end-time by adjusting the slider on waveform?

Comment: library does not allow to set start-time and end-time  .

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is one that allows users to interact with the waveform out of the box.

You could use [react-native-audiowaveform](https://github.com/juananime/react-native-audiowaveform) to show the waveform, and then capture the user's touches.